# Could we add our menu items in Gitkit Starter kit "Sign In cum User Info " ( #navbar )?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-identity-toolkit

Could we add our menu items in [Starter kit Gitkit NavBar](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend) ?
There are two list items in the drop down : `Manage Account` and `Sign Out`.
Is it possible to add a third option with a URL link ( say like `Update Profile` ) ?

The html for the `#navbar` gets loaded through Javascript code of Gitkit.

I use GAE Python.

Possible solutions which I could think of are :
After my webpage loads completely, I could add my own `<li>` items to the list of dropdown menu provided by `#navbar`.
Or
Write a custom "Sign In cum User Info " ( #navbar ) widget.

Is there a better and simpler approach ?

**MY REQUEST TO GITKIT TEAM FOR ENHANCEMENT**
It would be great if we could provide our custom menu items along with their URL links as options to below JS code which loads `#navbar` :

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton(
    '#navbar', // accepts any CSS selector
    {
      widgetUrl: "http://www.mywebsite.com/oauth2callback",
      signOutUrl: "/", 

      // Example of possible solution ( my suggestion ): 
      custom_menu_item__1__name : "item_1", // My Custom Menu Item 1 
      custom_menu_item__1__link : "http://site/link_url_1", 
      :: 
      custom_menu_item__n__name : "item_1", // My Custom Menu Item n 
      custom_menu_item__n__link : "http://site/link_url_1", 
    }
  );
</script>
```

[image: ShowMyHall User Card menu]

**UPDATE**
Temporary Fix = I have added the needed menu options using jquery temporarily. Code snippet provided below to help anyone with similar needs till official solution arrives :

On page load,

```
custom_menu_add_job_id = setInterval(function(){ 
        add_custom_menu(); 
    }, 5000); 

function add_custom_menu(){ 
    if ($("#navbar").find(".gitkit-user-card-menu").length){ 
        $(".gitkit-user-card-menu").append($("<li class='gitkit-user-card-menuitem' id='smh_user_profile' tabindex='0'> <img src='/images/person_32x32.png' class='user_profile_menu_icon' > Profile </li>")
            .click(function(){ 
                window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/user/"; 
            }) 
        ); 
        clearInterval(custom_menu_add_job_id); 
    } 
}
```

If you want, you could check it live at [ShowMyHall](http://www.showmyhall.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Customized menu items are now supported in Google Identity Toolkit javascript widget. Examples:

```
window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton(
  '#navbar', // accepts any CSS selector
  {
    widgetUrl: "...",
    dropDownMenu: [
        {
          'label': 'Check Configuration',
          'url': '/config'
        },
        {
          'label': 'Sign out',
          'handler': function() {google.identitytoolkit.signOut();}
        },
        {
          'label': 'Manage Account',
          'handler': function() {google.identitytoolkit.manageAccount();}
        },
      ]
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Jin. Would it be possible to share a ( even tentative ) time frame for its availability ?

Comment: We will try to support this customization in a couple of weeks.

Comment: The feature is live now. Will update the answer with details.

Comment: @JinLiu, what would be the easiest way to customize the look of this widget? For example, how can I show just the user image with dropdown on mobile screens in the widget to keep the widget size small?

Comment: @JinLiu Could we give images too along with text labels in the dropdown similar to what I have implemented [here](http://www.showmyhall.com/?default_country_id=IN&default_state_id=KA&default_city_id=BL) ? 
I mean do you allow us to give html content in the `label` ?

Comment: We don't support html strings for the label. It was not designed for that. I will provide you with a way to bypass that in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Until this feature arrives, I also implemented a similar temporary fix that you outlined at the end of your question. I got around using a timer as follows (note that my gitkit is using the div `login`):

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#login").hover(function() {
            add_custom_menu_items();
        })
    });

    function add_custom_menu_items(){
        if ($("#login").find(".gitkit-user-card-menu").length == 1){
            if ($("#my_data_link").length == 0) {
                $(".gitkit-user-card-menu li:eq(0)").after($('<li class="gitkit-user-card-menuitem" id="my_data_link" tabindex="0"><a href="/my_data/">My data</a></li>'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically when you hover over the div it adds the menu item, but only if it hasn't already been added.

Answer (score 0):

The navbar drop down menu does not support images but if you really need that, here's a hacky way to do it in jquery:

```
var config = {...}; // your config which includes the custom drop down menu.
// Render button on load. (now supported)
window.onload = function() {
  window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton(
    '#navbar', // accepts any CSS selector
    config);
  // This will modify the html content of the first option in drop down menu.
  // Make menu dom changes.
  jQuery('#navbar li:first-child').html('<img src="img.png">My Label');
}
```