# Menu Item Customization for Google Identity Toolkit (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-identity-toolkit

I've been trying to incorporate gitkit login into our web application's (python + GAE) existing login system and UI layout so have been looking for ways to customize away from the default sign-in button and signed-in menu format

I've seen a couple of posts that mention this is now implemented but haven't seen any docs or detailed discussions on the latest capabilities / examples

Would anyone have any sample code or references that can show me the extent of the customization possible? I've read comments that changing the menu items is possible but no docs.. is it also possible to create our own buttons and break away from the default dropdown? i.e. an independent sign out button, maybe using widget?mode=logout..

Any ideas would be very helpful!

Have been referencing the following discussions:

- [Could we add our menu items in Gitkit Starter kit "Sign In cum User Info " ( #navbar )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540583/could-we-add-our-menu-items-in-gitkit-starter-kit-sign-in-cum-user-info-na)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/google-identity-toolkit/gft_j55DUFg

Comment: Code sample has been given in the answer to the first discussion you referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540583/could-we-add-our-menu-items-in-gitkit-starter-kit-sign-in-cum-user-info-na/31735492#31735492.

Comment: Thanks Jin, I used the code there before but signout then just doesn't respond... my original code based on the quick start example was working before (see below):

also, is there a way to use a standalone signout button without calling google.identitytoolkit.signInButton? I'm trying to incorporate gitkit into our existing structure, thanks!

original code:
     window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton(
       '#navbar', // accepts any CSS selector
       {
         widgetUrl: "/widget",
         signOutUrl: "/",
   //      popupMode: true,
   //      loginFirst: true,
       }
     );

Comment: You have to specify the sign out url in config for sign out to work.

Comment: You can also set the config fields via google.identitytoolkit.setConfig({signOutUrl: '/', widgetUrl: '...', ...}); You will be able to call sign out directly: google.identitytoolkit.signOut()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jin Liu: Code sample has been given in the answer to the first discussion you referred stackoverflow.com/questions/31540583/….

And from bojeil:
You have to specify the sign out url in config for sign out to work.

You can also set the config fields via google.identitytoolkit.setConfig({signOutUrl: '/', widgetUrl: '...', ...}); You will be able to call sign out directly: google.identitytoolkit.signOut()